# Find the formula for $n*S_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $1*S_n$ denote $1+2+3+4+5...+n.$

Let $2*S_n$ denote $1*S_1 + 1*S_2 + 1*S_3 +... + 1*S_n.$

Similarly, let $3*S_n$ denote $2*S_1 + 2*S_2 + 2*S_3 +... + 2*S_n.$

and so on.

Find the formula for $n*S_n.$

Note: $n*S$  is not multiplication. It is a new notation.

Comment: First try to find a nice formula for $S_{n}$.

Comment: May be http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example computation to help you find a general formula for $k\star S_n$ which may be proven by induction. Observe that
$$
3\star S_n=\sum_{m=1}^n2\star S_{m}=\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m1\star S_j=
\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^j\binom{i}{1}
$$
At this point use the identity
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}
$$
repeatedly to unravel the sum. Indeed
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^j\binom{i}{1}=
\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\binom{j+1}{2}
=\sum_{m=1}^n\binom{m+2}{3}
=\binom{n+3}{4}.
$$
On the basis of this conmputation we may think that 
$$
k\star S_n=\binom{n+k}{k+1}
$$
which you may prove by induction.

Comment: Thank you Foobaz John.The answer indeed is $2n$ choose $(n+1)$.